# Random Number in MySqli Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am android developer and have not much knowledge of php. currently I am working for make backend of my android application. I have quote table with about 1000 row in it. I am trying to update some row with below query.

```
$randomnumbershare = (rand(10,50));
    $randomnumberlike = (rand(10,50));
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_quotes SET qu_status=0, qu_like=$randomnumberlike,qu_share=$randomnumbershare,qu_favorite=0, qu_time=Now() ORDER BY _quid ASC ");
```

I want set qu_like and qu_share with random number from 10 to 50. its working fine but have only one issue that it's setting same number in all row, instead I want different number in all row. Anyone can please suggest me how can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Your **issue** is not clear and your update query has no *WHERE* Clause.

Comment: @FrayneKonok I do not want go with WHERE because I want run it for all row...not any special row

Comment: So your *share* and *like* will be same value for all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you don't have a where clause, that means that the update is going to update all the rows in the table, if you want to have different values you need to do the update inside a for or while statement to repeat the update and add a where clause that matches every id of the table on every cicle.

Now you have this:

```
$randomnumbershare = (rand(10,50));
$randomnumberlike = (rand(10,50));
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_quotes SET qu_status=0, qu_like=$randomnumberlike,qu_share=$randomnumbershare,qu_favorite=0, qu_time=Now() ORDER BY _quid ASC ");
```

But you need something like:

If you have a numeric id that goes from 1 to 1000 you can do something like

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 1000; $x++) 
{
    $randomnumbershare = (rand(10,50));
    $randomnumberlike = (rand(10,50));
    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_quotes SET qu_status=0, qu_like=$randomnumberlike,qu_share=$randomnumbershare,qu_favorite=0, qu_time=Now() where id=$x ORDER BY _quid ASC ");
}
```

That code do your update 1000 times, one update for each row you have in you table, now if you have a varchar id that is somethin more complex than a numeric sequence you need to add a query before that stores that ids into an array, something like:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select id from table_name");
$tableinfo = array();

foreach ($tableinfo as $tableid) 
{
    $randomnumbershare = (rand(10,50));
    $randomnumberlike = (rand(10,50));
    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_quotes SET qu_status=0, qu_like=$randomnumberlike,qu_share=$randomnumbershare,qu_favorite=0, qu_time=Now() where id=$tableid[id] ORDER BY _quid ASC ");
}
```

For n number of row thinking you have a sequence from 1 to x number you can do:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select id from table_name");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

for ($x = 1; $x <= $num_rows; $x++) 
{
    $randomnumbershare = (rand(10,50));
    $randomnumberlike = (rand(10,50));
    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_quotes SET qu_status=0, qu_like=$randomnumberlike,qu_share=$randomnumbershare,qu_favorite=0, qu_time=Now() where id=$x ORDER BY _quid ASC ");
}
```

Comment: sorry ! I am not php developer, can You please explain it little more ? Thanks

Comment: Sure, let me add another answer to give you some code

Comment: Thanks a lot sir !!

Comment: Done, commonly a lot of users asks to get a litlle investigation before posting questions like this, I think you can learn a lot asking and searching, please continue learning to become one day into someone who answer the questions too! Regards.

Comment: Hello sir ! Thanks for nice suggestion and your hard work for make it working ..... its working smooth as I want. We are controlling id from this code as I have understood for ($x = 1; $x <= 1000; $x++) . What I should change if I want run for all id instead from 1 to 1000 ? Thanks

Comment: If you have only squence of number between 1 to x number you can do a select of the table and get the number of rows, am I assuming well? to add it to the post

Comment: If You can it will help me for complete my task. Thanks sir !!

Comment: I have tried to do like this for ($x = 1 $x++) but its not working

Comment: That is not working because you need to tell to the for the initial value, the condition to end and at the end the increment, I update the post, check it please

Comment: Hi sir ! It's working fine....You are awesome developer....Thanks a lot :)